# Dropdown menu on hover dissapears (using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a navigation with the help of bootstrap. With css i made a submenu that appears on hover.
Only when i want to click a title in the submenu, the submenu dissapears before i can click it.

I have read on other threads that i have to add the following to the css:

```
.dropdown:hover  > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
```

}

I added it, but it's still not working. What am i doing wrong?

This is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robin2609/buw4wc1t/

Gr. Robin

Comment: I'm not able to get any type of sub-menu to appear only hovering. I have to click the title for any sub-menu to appear.

Comment: It does if you make the screen wider.  It doesn't for the smaller view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you have your padding only going down `10px` and then your submenu is below the gray. while your padding does not reach the end of the main menu and therefore when the hover comes off the `.nav > li > a` it is now hovering just `.nav` which doesn't keep the sub menu open.

Change padding in:

`.nav > li > a`

to:

```
.nav > li > a
{
    padding: 10px 13px 30px 13px;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/buw4wc1t/3/

Comment: @user2314339 when you get a chance can you accept the answer so others know this issue was resolved for you?  Thanks.